# How to screengrab/film Android screen?

Tags: android

Since ICS it became really easy to take a screenshot from within Android. In the presentations Google goes further than that by streaming/saving the whole content that is shown on the screen including sound directly from the device. How to achieve that? Do I need some extra HDMI certified screen grabbing cards consoles require?